# What does it mean that: "Home loan must be secured within 90% of the value of the property"

Tags: mortgage, home-loan, housing

I am applying for a home loan and I am unsure about some of the text received from the bank.

What does it mean that a home loan must be secured within 90% of the value of the property?

Does it mean that the loan can not be higher than $90 000 if the value of the property is $100 000?

Comment: Yes, in the US this is typically called a "90% Loan to Value," the bank lending you 90% of the current value of the home. The bank should be answering any questions you have regarding a loan they will give you.

Comment: You should have this as an answer Joe.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loan-to-value_ratio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the US this is typically called a "90% Loan to Value," the bank lending you 90% of the current value of the home.

If the loan to value number is high (80%+) the more likely you are to walk away from a mortgage if the payment becomes too difficult to continue.

In the most extreme cases during the buildup of the last housing bubble it was possible to get a loan that initially started with the loan amount being equal to the value of the home (100%). This worked well for the bank a long as the value of the home kept growing; because when the house was resold the owner made money and the bank was repaid in full. But when the bubble burst, even loans that had significant down payments were underwater. And if the down payment had been very small, the owner had nothing to lose by walking away.

If the LTV is below 80% the borrower can avoid getting private mortgage Insurance (PMI) or mortgage protection Insurance (MPI). These polices protect the lender if you default. They are very different than  fire insurance. These PMI or MPI policies are paid for by the borrower, but only protect the lender.

The bank should be answering any questions you have regarding a loan they will give you. I also believe that when applying for the loan, they will give you documents that explain these terms and many other aspects of mortgages.